# Preposition phrase after a conjunction

Tags: sentence-structure

In a dictionary, I find a sentence I can’t understand

> I tried to persuade him, but with little or no effect.

In this case, I don’t know what a preposition phrase does function in the sentence.

And I guess that a subject and a verb(it is) are omitted after a conjunction ‘but’.

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite normal use of a prepostional phrase, and it does have the same meaning as

> I tried to persuade him, but it [the attempt to persuade] was with little or no effect.

Or

> I tried to persuade him with little or no effect.

with the added implication that the prepostional phrase makes a contrast.

Compare this with similar constructions

> This is like your car, but in red.

(the red colour contrasts with your car)

> He plays cricket, but on the beach, not on grass.

(we expect cricket on grass, so "on the beach" contrasts with our expectation)